# C# - how to figure out which menu item was clicked in external application when SetWinEventHook handler is fired?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, events

I'm building a POC where I can inject new main menu items into any Windows application, with the idea of then having those custom menu items invoke custom logic.

So far, I've injected new menu with child items, and got SetWinEventHook handler to fire when EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUEND event is raised. I can execute custom code in the handler, but the problem is that I don't know which menu item was clicked, so I can't execute logic that needs to run when specific menu item is selected.

Snippets of code that I have -

```cs
public delegate void WinEventDelegate(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr SetWinEventHook(uint eventMin, uint eventMax, IntPtr hmodWinEventProc, WinEventDelegate lpfnWinEventProc, uint idProcess, uint idThread, uint dwflags);

private static readonly WinEventDelegate callback = new WinEventDelegate(EventCallback);
```

Adding the custom menu

```cs
 var newMenu = CreateMenu();
 InsertMenu(newMenu, 0, MF_BYPOSITION, 10001, "Item 1");
 InsertMenu(newMenu, 1, MF_BYPOSITION, 10002, "Item 2");
 AppendMenu(menu, MF_POPUP, newMenu, "My Menu Section");
```

I'm then setting the hook

```cs
public void SetEventHook()
{
    var result = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUEND, EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUEND, IntPtr.Zero, callback, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNTHREAD);            

    Console.WriteLine($"SetWinEventHook returned {result}");
}
```

And finally delegate handler that fires when menu item is clicked

```cs
public static void EventCallback(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime)
{
    Process.Start("mspaint");
}
```

The problem I have is that there is nothing when EventCallback fires that will help me identify which menu item was selected. I thought that idObject param would have the id of the menu item selected, but it always returns -3, regardless of which menu item is selected (custom or already existing).

Is there a way that I can figure out which menu item was selected and use that to drive custom logic inside the handler?

Comment: You can use [IUIAutomation::AddAutomationEventHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uiautomationclient/nf-uiautomationclient-iuiautomation-addautomationeventhandler) to register a method that handles Microsoft UI Automation [**UIA_Invoke_InvokedEventId** or **UIA_SelectionItem_ElementSelectedEventId**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-supportmenuitemcontroltype#required-control-patterns) event on your menu items. [A WPF sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-events-for-clients#see-also).

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into UIAutomationClient but I was hoping to be able to achieve this just by using Win APIs.

Comment: [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) is a core system API. You do not need to use the [managed UI Automation classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview).

Answer (score 0):

Using the handler of [Handling General UI Automation Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-howto-implement-event-handlers#handling-general-ui-automation-events), I can add it on a menu item element of Visual Studio (WPF [FrameworkId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-automation-element-propids)). The applications with XAML FrameworkId need extra effort. [Accessibility tools - Inspect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects) is helpful when doing this.

```
int Element(IUIAutomation* automation)
{
    // Get the element under the cursor
// Use GetPhysicalCursorPos to interact properly with
// High DPI
    POINT pt;
    GetPhysicalCursorPos(&pt);

    IUIAutomationElement* pAtMouse;
    HRESULT hr = automation->ElementFromPoint(pt, &pAtMouse);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    // Get the element's name and print it
    BSTR name;
    hr = pAtMouse->get_CurrentName(&name);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        wprintf(L"Element's Name: %s \n", name);
        SysFreeString(name);


        VARIANT v;
        pAtMouse->GetCurrentPropertyValue(UIA_IsInvokePatternAvailablePropertyId,&v);
        if (v.boolVal)
        {
            pAtMouse->GetCurrentPropertyValue(UIA_FrameworkIdPropertyId,&v);

            CONTROLTYPEID id{};
            pAtMouse->get_CurrentControlType(&id);

            IUIAutomationInvokePattern* pattern;
            pAtMouse->GetCurrentPatternAs(UIA_InvokePatternId, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pattern));

            EventHandler* pEHTemp = new EventHandler();
            HRESULT h = automation->AddAutomationEventHandler(UIA_Invoke_InvokedEventId, pAtMouse, TreeScope_Element, NULL, (IUIAutomationEventHandler*)pEHTemp);
            if (h == S_OK) {

            }
            pEHTemp->Release();
            pattern->Release();
        }
    }

    // Clean up our COM pointers
    pAtMouse->Release();
    return hr;
}

int main(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // Initialize COM and create the main Automation object
    IUIAutomation* g_pAutomation;
    CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(CUIAutomation), NULL,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(IUIAutomation),
        (void**)&g_pAutomation);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return (hr);

    bool quit = false;
    while (!quit)
    {
        SHORT leftControlMod = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LCONTROL);
        if (leftControlMod != 0)
        {
            Element(g_pAutomation);
        }
        quit = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE);
    }

    g_pAutomation->RemoveAllEventHandlers();
    g_pAutomation->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it solved. Needed to listen for EVENT_OBJECT_INVOKED event instead of EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUEND event.

With EVENT_OBJECT_INVOKED I get the id of the menu item that was clicked on in idChild param in event handler.

```
public void SetEventHook()
{
    var result = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_INVOKED, EVENT_OBJECT_INVOKED, IntPtr.Zero, callback, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNTHREAD);            

    Console.WriteLine($"SetWinEventHook returned {result}");
}

public static void EventCallback(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime)
{
    switch (idChild)
    {
        case 10001:
            Process.Start("mspaint");
            break;
        case 10002:
            Process.Start("calc");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```