How to detect cursor position and update what action was taken live on the desktop
I want to create a piece of code that can detect cursor's live position and update what action was taken on the desktop.
Basically,

first : it takes screenshot of the desktop every 0.5 or less seconds here's the code for it.

second : screenshot array or folder goes to a yolo pipeline where the cursor position is detected and a new array is created.
CursorArray = ['xaxis','yaxis', CursorType, CursorAction]
CursorType = ['Hand Gesture', 'Pointer cursor', 'writing cursor']

third : what action was taken by cursor
CursorAction
if CursorType == 'Hand Gesture' : CursorAction = 'Clicked on a URL'
if CursorType == 'Pointer cursor' : CursorAction = 'LEFT CLICK, HOVER'


(NOTE : on pointer cursor It will check the difference in next image so I'll write the code for left click or Hover was happend etc)
if CursorType == 'writing cursor' : CursorAction = 'COPYING A TEXT'

fourth : I also want to know how it will detect writing bar if someone is writing ?? :confused:

For the first part I figured it out and 3 part is as simple as I wrote in the above text. I need help with 2nd and 4th part Please.... and I also looked up for template matching in opencv but I will need atleast 1600 images for it but it will take forever to loop over every image like 1600 times in 32 px of a area so If I get a screen of 1080 P it will atleast take 10 mins I think to get the result on 1 image.
Thanks in Advance and Please help me thanks alot everyone!!!
#import pytesseract
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
import pyautogui, sys
import os
import time
from time import sleep
import re
from collections import defaultdict
from subprocess import call

#taskName = 
taskName = 'OpenNotepad'

def takingScreenshot():
    counterExample = 0
    counter = 0
    screenshotArray = []
    os.mkdir('D:\\pyautogui\\'+ str(taskName))
    while counterExample < 50:
        counterExample = counterExample + 1
        screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()    
        time.sleep(0.5)
        counter = counter + 1
        pathNew = ('D:\\pyautogui\\'+ str(taskName) + r'\screenshot' + str(counter) + '.png')
        print(type(screenshotArray) , len(screenshotArray))
        screenshotArray.append(screenshot)
    print(type(screenshotArray) , len(screenshotArray))
   
    #Converting the Screenshots into actuall images and saving in folder.
        screenshot.save(pathNew)

takingScreenshot()
#THIS FUNCTION IS WORKING PROPERLY AND SAVING IMAGES AS WELL


You can't detect the cursor position from the screenshot.  You'll need to use the Win32 GetCursorPos API to get that.  PyWin32 lets you do that.  You are, I assume, aware of the many open source applications that already do this kind of screen recording.  It would be more productive to start from there.

you don't take "screenshots" of a video. the notion of a screenshot is entirely different from decoding a video and wanting specific frames from the video.

@TimRoberts if he wants to detect cursor objects in a picture or video, sure he can do that. that's just object detection. given that cursors usually are from a small set of pictures, this could be done reasonably cheaply with template matching. this will only work on the mouse cursor though, because text carets vary a lot more (from program to program). -- I do agree that this is silly and OP should just record cursor position and state directly by using OS APIs

@OP your research into template matching is fraught with misunderstandings. you're new to this, so please discard all conclusions you've drawn about any of it.

@ChristophRackwitz okay so should I stick to template matching then ?

Or should I go for yolov8 custom training of dataset it will take 25623 number of images. 256 background colors * 2 black, white cursor * 3 types of cursor like hand,pointer, typing one?

@ChristophRackwitz or can you tell me is there a way I can teach a bot based on YouTube videos? I know that's silly question but I think it can be done.

GetCursorPos tells you where to look.  Then, you can check that very small rectangle for the cursor type.

train a "bot" on "youtube videos"? "can be done"? sure, if you're an AI researcher. otherwise, no.

@TimRoberts don't even need to look, call GetCursorInfo

I think you have confused the issue by using the word "video".  You aren't talking about monitoring a video here.  You are talking about grabbing a set of screenshots of a live system, right?

Thanks alot mates and a very thanks to @ChristophRackwitz I'll keep you guys updated with the progress. I am not an AI researcher I don't even know how to code properly but I will give a try to yolo v8 thingy It might help me to make this thing.

This reads like an "If all you have is a hammer, every problem looks like a nail" issue. If you need to know the current cursor position, just ask the OS (GetCursorPos()). That's hundreds of thousands of times less expensive than taking a screenshot and running it through a kernel. And it's reliable, too. It accounts for the cursor's hotspot location (which an image has no way of discovering) and also works when the user happens to be working with, say, a cursor editor where multiple cursor images are displayed at the same time.

Things just get worse from here. The assumption that the cursor shape was somehow reliable is unfounded. Whichever cursor is currently being displayed is at the sole discretion of the window implementation under the cursor. There are conventions, but nothing keeps an application author from displaying a cute unicorn cursor when the mouse is over a particular area of interest. Likewise, the cursor shape doesn't allow us to make assumptions about a user action taking place. Whatever problem you are trying to solve you're best advised to invest more time into understanding it.

note that this question started out a lot less clear than it is now. at least the title did.

You may utilize SetWinEventHook to simplify the task. For a use case, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77817262/c-sharp-how-to-figure-out-which-menu-item-was-clicked-in-external-application.
