I want to detect who causes a WM_COMMAND to be fired?
Background: I have an application with context menu, normal menu and accelerator.
I have a paste command and in case the context menu was opened with the mouse, the paste operation should use the mouse position / position of the context menu to execute the paste.
I checked WM_COMMAND and the parameter in wParam didn't help. Also I tried to check out what message was sent to the input queue, when the context menu is used.
But all I see is that the WM_COMMAND message is posted. Also when I use the accelerator I can't see any difference.
Also because using the BCG and new-MFC it seams that the information that an accelerator was used (HIWORD(wParam)) is hidden somehow.
Any idea how to detect the situation "Context Menu -> Command executed."?

Use different command IDs in the context menu, in the normal menu and in the accelerator. E.g. Put ID_EDIT_PASTE in the normal menu and put ID_EDIT_PASTE_CONTEXT into the context menu etc.

"in case the context menu was opened with the mouse" - That's an incredibly odd data point to use as a predicate. Just to get the obvious out of the way: The system doesn't record this information. If you need to know, you'll have to record it yourself. Once you do, and implement your vile scheme, how do you think this would fare when a user carefully positions their mouse cursor, and then presses [Shift]+[F10] (so they don't have to right-click and risk losing the carefully chosen cursor position)?

@IInspectable I know when the context menu is opened by the keyboard, the position is -1,-1.  It is not wo have an exact position but in case of knowing (nearly) where the user wants to place an action is helpful in my situation. If the context menu key is pressed we calculate a meaningful location out of selected items and something like a caret position...

Did you try SetWinEventHook? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77817262/c-sharp-how-to-figure-out-which-menu-item-was-clicked-in-external-application

I understand what you're trying to do. I just tried to illustrate how you're breaking your keyboard interface. The guiding principle for a quality GUI should be to always focus on the keyboard interface. This will generally get you very decent pointing device support already. If you wish to extend mouse support make sure not to break the keyboard interface (which is what you're planning to do). You can call GetMessagePos() in your WM_COMMAND handler and have a working UI regardless of how the context menu command was initiated.

@Jabberwocky's suggestion in the comments (using distinct command codes for where in the UI the user issued them) is probably the simplest way to distinguish between them.
For your particular need, that approach makes a lot of sense because the operations are indeed distinct:  either the user wants to (1) paste or (2) paste at the mouse location.  The code doing the pasting doesn't need to worry about where the command came from—that's a UI detail.  What it needs to know is whether to use the mouse position.
Another approach is to not have the pop-up menu actually send the command notifications.  When you call TrackPopupMenu, you can use the flags TPM_NONOTIFY | TPM_RETURNCMD.  With those flags set, when the user selects the option, TrackPopupMenu returns the ID of the selected menu item but does not send the WM_COMMAND notification.  So the code that calls TrackPopupMenu can examine the return value and decide how to handle it in that ... uh, context.

When you react on the right click in your working area, you can show and track the popup menu using e.g. CContextMenuManager::TrackPopupMenu. This way, you get the selected menu item directly.

The original answer already mentions about TrackPopupMenu.

The question was tagged with MFC, so I linked the MFC equivalent. Should I delete my answer?

Keep it. You got a vote.
